# Should we also allow questions on hammers?

Tags: discussion, allow

I know what you're thinking but hear me out, OK? I just read this article and it got me thinking: maybe we should start allowing hammer-related questions on the site. It seems they have more in common with photography than I'd realised.

Videography, no. But hammers? I have to say for me it's a yes.

http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2012/03/hammerforum-com

Comment: Hammers would be a topic for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4046918#4046918)

Comment: Hammers would be great, especially today!

Comment: @rfusca You already possess the banhammer. What more could you want? (A few nails, maybe...? ;))

Comment: wasn't this an april fools attempt?